# Audio trigger in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've coded up a quiz using javascript, I want to add sound effects when a user answers a question either correctly or incorrectly. Sounds will be different for correct and incorrect answers. Im just starting javascript and need this for a class project so any help would be greatly appreciated. I can upload the html and js code if anyone can help. I presume I have to use an onclick event with if or else statements but im not too sure how to do this.
Thanks

Comment: Look into HTML5 Audio, and triggering a `play` from a click. Here is one article on the subject: http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/introduction-to-the-html5-audio-tag-javascript-manipulation/

Comment: Post your code to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or a [plunk](http://plnkr.co).

Comment: Hi i've uploaded it to here, https://github.com/shanekwork/JavascriptProj thanks for the help. saving my life.com

Comment: Cool have it uploaded here now http://jsfiddle.net/shanek6/PwsSv/

Answer (score 1):

```
   <audio id="right">
        <source src="right.mp3">
    </audio>
   <audio id="wrong">
        <source src="wrong.mp3">
    </audio>
```

Then to play:

```
document.getElementById("right").play();
```

or

```
document.getElementById("wrong").play();
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, Im really lost as to where to put it in my code, would you mind if I uploaded it to github or I can paste it in here even if you could take a look at it.

Comment: It would be best for you to provide a jsfiddle example, like couzzi suggested